# NSTextField set maximum characters

Tags: max, nstextfield

Is there an easy way for me to set a limit on the amount of characters my NSTextField can have?  I don't want to have a counter then warn the user if it's over the limit, I want to set the limit so if it's past x characters that's it, they can't type anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out NSFormatter.  It can help you do what you're looking for and a lot more.  If you don't need something that complicated, you might try the NSTextField delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[Key-Value Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173-CJBDBHCB)** to ensure the max. length is never exceeded.

This would allow you to additionaly notify the user if the entered length was too long - or you could just quietly modify the value.